# Request assistance as to why my form will not validate properly

Tags: php, html

I have scoured this site for hints and tips as I re-learn PHP form validation.

The form created (using BS4) and code below are supposed to work together. They have been pieced together using information found here and W3 and from dissecting a few of the free templates out there.

It seemed so simple to work this out. But, I keep receiving incorrect validation from all fields in the form.

**name** - must be alpha only - validation never displays error when intentionally entering non-alpha chars

**email** - must comply with the input type 'email' - validation always catches this one and for some reason displays a tooltip... refusing to submit the form. I did not intentionally code for the tooltip and, can't see how to get rid of it OR duplicate it on other fields.

**subject** uses the input type 'subject' - But, the absence of a subject does not trigger the error display after submitting.

**message** - just has to be something - But, validation on the pre-submit status already displays the error condition.

When all data is entered, properly formatted, submitting the form erases all the data and, displays errors in every field.

I am not particularly good at hard coding. I own that. But, I think that I follow directions fairly well. And, this just isn't working as expected.

If anyone can point me in the right direction to get validation working on this form, I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

The page is HTML5, PHP 7, BS4.

```html
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]);?>" class="p-5 bg-white">

  <div class="mb-3 border-bottom">
    <h2 class="h4 text-black mb-5">Send us a Message</h2>
    <p>Note that All Fields are Required</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
      <label class="text-black" for="name"><font color="red" size="+2">* </font>Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
      <span class="list-group-item-danger"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row form-group">

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="email"><font color="red" size="+2">* </font>Your Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
      <span class="list-group-item-danger"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row form-group">

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="subject"><font color="red" size="+2">* </font>Subject</label>
      <input type="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $subject;?>">
      <span class="list-group-item-danger"><?php echo $subjectErr;?></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="message"><font color="red" size="+2">* </font>Your Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message here..." value="<?php echo $message;?>"></textarea>
      <span class="list-group-item-danger"><?php echo $messageErr;?></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row form-group">
    <div align="center" class="col-md-12">
      <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary btn-md text-white">
    </div>
  </div>


</form>
```

```
<!-- PHP Form validation script --> 

<?
// declare and empty local variables
$nameErr = $messageErr = $emailErr = $subjectErr = "";
$name = $message = $email = $subject =  "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required and can only contain alphabet text";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Roman Alphabet and Spaces Only";
    }
  }


  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email address is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Please Correct Invalid Email Address";
    }
  }

   if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
    $subjectErr = "Subject Cannot be Empty";
  } else {
    $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
    }    
  } 

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $messageErr = "Message Cannot be Empty";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<!-- END PHP Form Validation script -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, quite simply, it is mainly because your input fields are missing a `name` attribute. The ID is NEVER part of the POST array and all but the `message` textarea are missing the name. The validation is a little different here but essentially does the same things.

When submitting to the same page you can safely omit the form `action` completely - and it is better to do that than to rely upon `PHP_SELF` which is vulnerable to abuse.

Incidentally there is no `subject` field type in HTML.

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

    $name = $nameErr = $email = $emailErr = $subject = $subjectErr = $message = $messageErr = '';

    $use_inline_error_messages=true;
    $use_error_printout=true;

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        $errors=array();
        $args=array(
            'name'      =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'email'     =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
            'subject'   =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'message'   =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );

        foreach( array_keys( $args ) as $field ){
            if( empty( $_POST[ $field ] ) ) $errors[]=sprintf( 'The field "%s" is not set', $field );
        }
        foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
            if( !in_array( $field, array_keys( $args ) ) )$errors[]=sprintf( 'Unknown field "%s"', $field );
        }



        if( empty( $errors ) or $use_inline_error_messages ){

            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            extract( $_POST );


            if( empty( $name ) )$nameErr='Name is required and can only contain alphabet text';
            else {
                if( !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/',$name ) ) $nameErr = "Roman Alphabet and Spaces Only";
            }

            $email=filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
            if( empty( $email ) )$emailErr = "Email address is required";
            if( empty( $subject ) ) $subjectErr='Subject Cannot be Empty';
            if( empty( $message ) ) $messageErr='Message Cannot be Empty';

            /* here, if there are no errors with form validation and error variables are empty - send email */
            if( !$nameErr && !$emailErr && !$subjectErr && !$messageErr && empty( $errors ) ){
                http_response_code( 200 );
                exit( mail( $email, $subject, $message ) );
            }

        }
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .required-star:after{content:'*';color:red}
            pre.errors{color:red}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method='post' class='p-5 bg-white'>
            <?php
                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $errors ) && $use_error_printout ){
                    printf('<pre class="errors">%s</pre>', implode( PHP_EOL, $errors ) );

                }
            ?>
          <div class='mb-3 border-bottom'>
            <h2 class='h4 text-black mb-5'>Send us a Message</h2>
            <p>Note that All Fields are Required</p>
          </div>

          <div class='row form-group'>
            <div class='col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0'>
              <label class='text-black required-star' for='name'>Your Name</label>
              <input type='text' name='name' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $name;?>'>
              <span class='list-group-item-danger'><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='row form-group'>

            <div class='col-md-12'>
              <label class='text-black required-star' for='email'>Your Email Address</label>
              <input type='email' name='email' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $email;?>'>
              <span class='list-group-item-danger'><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='row form-group'>

            <div class='col-md-12'>
              <label class='text-black required-star' for='subject'>Subject</label>
              <input type='text' name='subject' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $subject;?>'>
              <span class='list-group-item-danger'><?php echo $subjectErr;?></span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='row form-group'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
              <label class='text-black required-star' for='message'>Your Message</label>
              <textarea name='message' cols='30' rows='7' class='form-control' placeholder='Your message here...' ><?php echo $message;?></textarea>
              <span class='list-group-item-danger'><?php echo $messageErr;?></span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='row form-group'>
            <div align='center' class='col-md-12'>
              <input type='submit' value='Send Message' class='btn btn-primary btn-md text-white'>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I replaced ID attribute with name on all input tags. And, sure enough, the validation functioned as expected. I still have that nagging little displayed-error on the "message" text area that I can't get rid of. But, the test data return on several passes indicate that it is working - as far as validation is concerned.
Now, I will clone the page and attempt it your way per the above code snippet.
Question asked and answered. Thank You!

Comment: Do you have any idea why the message field doesn't respond in the same way as the rest of the fields? I am testing your code as-is. And, still the message field is not cooperating. When all fields are populated and let's say the email address is improperly formatted... The error is trapped and the proper message displays... But, the typed message gets erased on submit. The other fields don't do this. And, I cannot see what makes it different. compact code BTW.

Comment: I do know and I'm sorry for not spotting that earlier.. check edited version. Essentially a `textarea` does not have a `value` attribute - the content is instead written between opening and closing tags

Comment: Definitely did not know that. And, with that change, it now retains the typed text throughout multiple validation passes. Again, Thank you! This has been VERY interesting work.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother. But, I have been tracing the code looking for the exit point - where to insert the include that builds the mail headers and executes the php mail() script. For the life of me, I can't see where everything is resolved and ready to build/send the message. This is a needy request. But, could you point the off-ramp out to me?

Comment: Ah! I see what you did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not correct `$_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]`, remove all spaces just like that `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`

```
<!-- PHP Form validation script --> 
<?

// declare and empty local variables
$nameErr = $messageErr = $emailErr = $subjectErr = "";
$name = $message = $email = $subject =  "";
var_dump($_SERVER);
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required and can only contain alphabet text";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $nameErr = "Roman Alphabet and Spaces Only";
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email address is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Please Correct Invalid Email Address";
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $subjectErr = "Subject Cannot be Empty";
    } else {
        $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
    }    
} 
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $messageErr = "Message Cannot be Empty";
} else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
}
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
<form method="post" action="
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" class="p-5 bg-white">
    <div class="mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h2 class="h4 text-black mb-5">
            Send us a Message
        </h2>
        <p>
            Note that All Fields are Required
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
            <label class="text-black" for="name"><font color="red" size="+2">
                * 
                </font>Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" value="
<?php echo $name ?? '';?>">
            <span class="list-group-item-danger"><?php echo $nameErr ?? '';?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="text-black" for="email"><font color="red" size="+2">
                * 
                </font>Your Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="
<?php echo $email ?? '';?>">
            <span class="list-group-item-danger"><?php echo $emailErr ?? '';?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="text-black" for="subject"><font color="red" size="+2">
                * 
                </font>Subject</label>
            <input type="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" value="
<?php echo $subject ?? '';?>">
            <span class="list-group-item-danger"><?php echo $subjectErr ?? '';?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="text-black" for="message"><font color="red" size="+2">
                * 
                </font>Your Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message here..." value="
<?php echo $message ?? '';?>"></textarea>
            <span class="list-group-item-danger"><?php echo $messageErr ?? '';?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div align="center" class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary btn-md text-white">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't know what happened in the snippet. But, those spaces do not appear in the original. And, the page does refer back to itself. So, at least that much is working.

Comment: I marked the answer that worked for the question asked. Your suggestion, while very much appreciated, was not applicable - as there were no spaces in my original code... only in the posted snippet (as explained above). RamRaider provided the answer that made the validation process effective. Am I missing some point of SE etiquette here?